# I am getting "Object Required" error message

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to stick a news scroller on the home page of our website.

I am a bit confused by the error message I am getting because I get it on one PC but not on another:

> Object Required

I am using the below code but the following line keeps throwing `Object Required` error when I use this file as a web user control on my `default.aspx page`:

```
el2.style.height='<%=box_height %>';
```

As a result, the news is not scrolling.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<a href="#"><uc1:NewsScroller ID="NewsScroller1" runat="server" /></a>

<script language="VB" runat="server">
    Public box_TextColor As String = "black"
    Public box_height As Integer = 150
    Public box_width As Integer = 166
    Public box_padding As String = "0 0 0 20"    
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" for="window" event="onload">
// <!CDATA[
    return window_onload()
// ]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <!CDATA[

// <!--
    var speed = 2;
    function init(){
        var el = document.getElementById("newsdiv");
        el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        el.style.height='<%=box_height %>';
        el.style.width='<%=box_width %>';
        el.style.padding='<%=box_padding %>';
        el.style.color='<%=box_TextColor %>';

        var el2 = document.getElementById("newsdiv-p1");
        el2.style.height='<%=box_height %>';
        var el3 = document.getElementById("newsdiv-p2");

        el3.style.height='<%=box_height %>';  
        //alert(document.getElementById("newsdiv-p2").style.height+document.getElementById("newsdiv-p2").style.height);
        scrollFromBottom();  
    }

    var go = 0;
    var timeout = '';
    function scrollFromBottom(){

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        var el = document.getElementById("newsdiv");
        if(el.scrollTop >= el.scrollHeight-'<%=box_height %>'){
            el.scrollTop = 0;
        };

        el.scrollTop = el.scrollTop + speed;
        if(go == 0){
            timeout = setTimeout("scrollFromBottom()",50);
        };
    }

    function stop(){
        go = 1;
   }

   function startit(){
       go = 0;
      scrollFromBottom();
    }
// -->

    function window_onload() {
    init();

}
// ]]>
</script>


<%--<asp:Panel ID="newsdiv" runat="server" onmouseout="startit();" onmouseover="stop();">--%>
    <div id="newsdiv"  onmouseout="startit();" onmouseover="stop();"  >
        <p id="newsdiv-p1" class="spacer"></p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNews" runat="server" Text="News..."></asp:Label>
        <p id="newsdiv-p2" class="spacer"></p>
    </div>
<%--</asp:Panel>--%>
```

@Marcel, I suppose you mean the source (right-click, view source and copy the code)?

If so, here it is and again, thanks

```
    <script type="text/javascript" for="window" event="onload">
// <!CDATA[
return window_onload()
// ]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <!CDATA[

// <!--
var speed = 2;

$(document).ready(function init(){
  var el = document.getElementById("newsdiv");
  el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  el.style.height='150';
  el.style.width='166';
   el.style.padding='0 0 0 20';
   el.style.color='black';

var el2 = document.getElementById("newsdiv-p1");

  el2.style.height='150';
var el3 = document.getElementById("newsdiv-p2");

  el3.style.height='150';  
  //alert(document.getElementById("newsdiv-p2").style.height+document.getElementById("newsdiv-p2").style.height);
  scrollFromBottom();


 }); 
var go = 0;
var timeout = '';
function scrollFromBottom(){

  clearTimeout(timeout);
  var el = document.getElementById("newsdiv");
  if(el.scrollTop >= el.scrollHeight-'150'){
    el.scrollTop = 0;

  };
  el.scrollTop = el.scrollTop + speed;
  if(go == 0){
    timeout = setTimeout("scrollFromBottom()",60);
  };
}

function stop(){
  go = 1;
}

function startit(){
  go = 0;
  scrollFromBottom();
}
// -->

function window_onload() {
init();

}

// ]]>
</script>
<div id="newsdiv"  onmouseout="startit();" onmouseover="stop();"  >
<p id="newsdiv-p1" class="spacer">
    </p>
    <span id="NewsScroller1_lblNews"><a href='#' OnClick=javascript:window.open('newsDetail.aspx?NewsID=10','NewsDetail','width=800,height=600;toolbar=no;');><font face='verdana' size='2' color='#184D68'>Steve's Birthday</font><br><br><a href='#' OnClick=javascript:window.open('newsDetail.aspx?NewsID=15','NewsDetail','width=800,height=600;toolbar=no;');><font face='verdana' size='2' color='#184D68'>Our Anniversary</font><br><br><a href='#' OnClick=javascript:window.open('newsDetail.aspx?NewsID=14','NewsDetail','width=800,height=600;toolbar=no;');><font face='verdana' size='2' color='#184D68'>Jessie's Birthday</font><br><br></span>
    <p id="newsdiv-p2" class="spacer"></p>
</div>
```

I am still trying to wrap my head on how this great forum works. Yesterday, I was able to see a button that says, "Add comment". Since today, I have not been able to see it. I guess my question is, how do you log back in so you are able to add comments, etc? Login appears to be cookie-driven which means that your priviledges disappear once you close the browser, no?

Comment: This happens all times in different browsers due to different JS engines, bugs etc

Comment: @Tomas: That's a *very* general remark you could put beneath almost every question regarding web development and no, that's not the cause of the trouble in this case.

Comment: Can you show what the HTML looks like as it is sent to the browser? I can't ‘read’ ASP.net and fear that that part `asp:Panel ID="newsdiv" …` interferes with your `#newsdiv` (IDs are not only case-sensitive, but also must be unique). BTW, `setTimeout("scrollFromBottom()",50)` is **not** how to use `setTimeout`, don't feed strings to it, it has the same pitfalls as using `eval`. In this case, just use `setTimeout(scrollFromBottom,50)`.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the error message ‘Object required’ means that variable `el2` doesn't contain an `HTMLElement` object.

ID's of elements are case-sensitive, so you can't get the element

```
<p id="newsdiv-p1" class="spacer"></p>
```

using

```
var el2 = document.getElementById("newsDiv-p1");
```

Moreover, you can't access elements that have not been rendered yet. Put your function in an `onload` handler or *after* the markup.

BTW, the `language` attribute of the `script` element [has been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) long ago.

---

**Update:** this piece of code

```
<script type="text/javascript" for="window" event="onload">
// <!CDATA[
    return window_onload()
// ]]>
</script>
```

uses an [IE-specific way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533746%28VS.85%29.aspx) to attach an event handler. **Never use it!**

Instead, use a [DOM level 2 method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or just

```
window.onload = window_onload;
```

Comment: Ok, duh, I get @Marcel's point about case-sensitivity of javascript. sorry, a bit slow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the DOM is ready before you start to interact with it.

I'd recommend using jQuery and wrapping your DOM-interactive code in the [.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703734/i-am-getting-object-required-error-message) event hander, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   init();
});
```

That way you can be sure that all your elements exist before you start to reference them, as stated in the [jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The handler passed to .ready() is
>   guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the
>   best place to attach all other event
>   handlers and run other jQuery code.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Which of the functions should I wrap the DOM around, all of the functions?

Comment: @simflex:: if you just wrap the call to `init()` and remove the `window_onload` stuff then that should be fine.  However, also see @Marcel Korpel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

put your script tags after newsDiv. I think the problem arises because the html hasn't rendered yet.

Comment: You guys are absolutely fantastic. Why did it take me this long to discover this great place. @Marcel Korpel, I did try your suggestion before, and again now but I suppose I am doing it incorrectly because it isn't helping. Can you guys help rearrange for me as I am still trying to get a handle on js. Many thanks all. These are fantastic responses.

Comment: @simflex, please comment on my answer as I won't be notified if you call me where I'm not in the conversation yet. Anyway, what do you mean by ‘it isn't helping’? What does your current code look like? Can you adjust the code in your question?

Comment: Please forgive me @Marcel and all you wonderful helpers. I didn't get a chance to respond before I was asked to go offsite. I have updated the js with what I could ascertain from your posts. The "Object Required" error is gone but the text is not scrolling as it does with another PC I tested with. Again, very sorry for late response. It was not intentional and thanks alot for your assistance.

Comment: @simflex: No problem at all, I don't mind if someone has a life outside of the interwebz, as I do have myself.

Comment: @Marcel, any ideas why the text is not scrolling based on modified code above?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have java script functions available in your page. Some times you get such errors when no method is accessible.