# Executing JavaScript in the <head>, getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript

I have following code

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function foo(q) {
    this.run=function(color){
        var x=document.getElementById("ff");
        alert(x); // <----x=null
    };

}

var q=new foo();
q.run("yellow");
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ff"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

does anyone has idea why `x=null`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703734/i-am-getting-object-required-error-message/5703932#5703932 BTW, the `language` attribute of the `script` element [has been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) long ago.

Comment: If I got a penny for every question on SO about this issue ... `:)`

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 23):

It's `null` because you're calling the script before the DOM has been loaded.

Wrap your script in a function which will be invoked `onload`, e.g.:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var q = new foo();
    q.run('yellow');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time the script is parsed, only the `<html>` and `<head>` tags have been loaded. There are several ways you can fix this:

1. Put the `<script>` tags at the end of your document, instead of at the beginning
2. Put the Javascript in another file and load it in the head with `<script type="text/javascript" src="OtherFile.js"></script>`
3. Wrap the entire function in `window.onload = function () { yourCodeHere(); }`, which will halt execution of your code until the window has loaded.

Comment: This is not entirely true: the DOM works with *elements*, not tags. That means that the `head` element is not yet completely inserted into the DOM and you can't reliably manipulate the `head` element. Moreover, (2) will not solve the issue, it doesn't matter whether you include code inline or in an external script, JavaScript scripts are executed sequentially.

Comment: Marcel, thanks for the clarification. As far as your second point goes, isn't loading a script in another file the same as running it with async=false?

Answer (score 1):

This JS code will run before the DOM is ready so the node will not be found. To perform execution only once the DOM is ready, you could use the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) event handler.