# JavaScript Function works in body but not in Head

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JS as part of my studies and at the moment I am trying some examples from W3Schools and am stuck on JS Functions page. The link of the page is:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_return

If I use the example code them the code runs perfectly just as below code:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <script>
    function myFunction(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(3, 4);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But if I take the script portion of the above code inside Head tags just like below code then the function does not execute at all and I do not get any value:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function myFunction(a, b) {
        return a * b;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(3, 4);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone point me where I am doing wrong and how to fix this issue.

Cheers,

Comment: Use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) in `head` when binding events. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772994/how-to-have-a-script-in-the-head-add-script-at-the-end-of-the-body/29773084#29773084) will help you

Comment: @Tushar - what are the alternatives for IE8 or less :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing JavaScript in the <head>, getElementById returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704924/executing-javascript-in-the-head-getelementbyid-returns-null)

Comment: @JaromandaX Here is [fallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Cross-browser_fallback) solution. IE8 is on it's extinction, at present time nobody care about _IE8_

Comment: This question has nothing to do with head vs. body, but buggy code vs non-buggy code. It is not a duplicate, since in the non-working version in the OP, `getElementById` that is found in the head is only executed by clicking on an element on the body, so `demo` will definitely be known by that time.

Comment: @Tushar - I certainly don't give a rats about IE less than 11, let alone 8 or less, but every second time I answer some question here it's all "what about IE < 9", and I'm too polite to say what I really want to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple issues. Here's how to fix it:

First off, you functions `return` a value at the end of the function, after processing parameters. Having a `return` at the beginning is bad.

Second, you've got to call the function with arguments from the `onclick` HTML attribute. Right now, there's nothing in the function call `myFunction()`. It should look like `myFunction(3, 4)`.

Lastly, what was the point of calling `myFunction()` within the function declaration? That doesn't make sense.

I've adjusted your code with comments to help you make sense of it. This should be helpful.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction(a, b) {
      // Return is usually the last thing you do in a function.
      // Also, don't call a function from within the function.
      // Instead, put what you had in return in the demo element's innerHTML.

      return document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b; // a * b,
      // not 3 * 4.
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo"> </p>
  <!-- Also, there were no arguments here. You need to specify arguments in 
    the onclick event -->
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(3, 4)">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling `myFunction` in the click handler you are not passing any parameters to it, also the first statement in it is a return statement which means the second param will not get executed.

What you need to do is to define the function such a way that it will take 2 parameters then will multiply them and put the result to `#demo` element.

Then on click of the button, you can call the function with the desired parameters

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction(a , b) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id = "demo"> </p>
        <button type="button" onclick = "myFunction(3, 4)">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also use `DOMContentLoaded`. As inline handlers is _bad_ practice

Answer (score 0):

There are significant errors in this function definition:

```
function myFunction(a , b) {
return a * b;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(3, 4);
}
```

First, you call it using `myFunction()`, which assigns both `a` and `b` the value `undefined`; when you multiply them, you get `NaN`, which you return. When you return from a function, nothing else in the function gets executed. And if you didn't return, you would get into an infinite recursive loop (which would probably end in a stack overflow) as you keep calling the function from itself again and again.

These errors are the reason the script is not working; nothing to do with it being in the head.

Answer (score -1):

Because you had return in myFunction and

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(3, 4);
```

not executed. You could change into like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jk9c099z/)

```
<head>
   <script>
      function myFunction(a , b) {
         return a * b;
      }
     function buttonClick() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(3, 4);
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id = "demo"> </p>
    <button type="button" onclick = "buttonClick()">Click me</button>
</body>
```